# Libelf adding entries to string table of existing elf

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to add an entry to the (symbol) string table in an existing ELF binary using `libelf`. Right now, I'm using `elf_getdata` to get the data descriptor, allocating a new larger `d_buf` and changing its `d_size`, copying over the string to the end of the buffer, changing the `sh_size` of the applicable shdr, using `gelf_update_shdr` and then `elf_update` to write it. This doesn't error, and successfully increases the size of the string table, but it fails to actually write the new data: `readelf` reports that the new string is `.sym` if I try to allocate a four-character string - i.e. it's just reading from the values in whatever's after the string table.

Here is some code that can replicate this - it reads in ELF data and then tries to add the value to the strtab:

```c
#include <libelf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <gelf.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t strtab_put(Elf_Scn** scns, GElf_Shdr* shdrs, int which, char *string) { // put value into strtab
    for (; *scns; scns++) {
        if (shdrs->sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
            if (which) {
                which--; // just refer to strtabs by numeric index
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        shdrs++;
    }
    if (!*scns) return -1;
    Elf_Data *strtab;
    strtab = elf_getdata(*scns, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < strtab->d_size; i++) {
        if (!strcmp((char*)strtab->d_buf + i, string)) { // if it's already there don't allocate a new one
            return i;
        }
    }   
    strtab->d_buf = (char*)realloc((char*)strtab->d_buf, strtab->d_size + strlen(string) + 1); // realloc enough space for the new string
    strcpy((char*)strtab->d_buf + strtab->d_size, string);
    size_t oldsize = strtab->d_size; // also the offset into the buffer
    strtab->d_size += strlen(string) + 1; // update data and shdr size
    shdrs->sh_size += strlen(string) + 1;
    gelf_update_shdr(*scns, shdrs);
    return oldsize;
}

int main() {
    elf_version(EV_CURRENT);
    int fd = open("elftest", O_RDWR, 0);
    Elf *elf = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_RDWR, NULL); // load in elf from file
    elf_flagelf(elf, ELF_C_SET, ELF_F_LAYOUT);
    GElf_Ehdr ehdr;
    gelf_getehdr(elf, &ehdr);
    size_t numphdrs;
    elf_getphdrnum(elf, &numphdrs);
    GElf_Phdr phdrs[numphdrs]; // read in phdrs
    for (int i = 0; i < numphdrs; i++) {
        gelf_getphdr(elf, i, &phdrs[i]);
    }
    Elf_Scn* scns[32];
    GElf_Shdr shdrs[32]; // read in shdrs
    size_t numshdrs;
    Elf_Scn* curscn = NULL;
    while ((curscn = elf_nextscn(elf, curscn)) != NULL) {
        scns[numshdrs] = curscn;
        gelf_getshdr(curscn, &shdrs[numshdrs]);
        numshdrs++;
    }
    scns[numshdrs] = NULL;
    printf("Offset of test: %lx\n", strtab_put(scns, shdrs, 1, "test"));
    elf_update(elf, ELF_C_WRITE);
    elf_end(elf);
    close(fd);
}
```

Is this even the correct way to go about this? Am I forgetting some attribute I have to update, some `gelf_update_foo` call, etc.? Do I have to update the `sh_offset` values for every section after it?

Comment: You might want to add code showing what's not working.

Comment: Are you trying to change `ET_REL` or `ET_EXEC` / `ET_DYN`? The former should work, the latter will very likely not work.

Comment: I think it was `ET_DYN`, but even changing it to `ET_EXEC` (i.e. recompiling with `-no-pie`) it still fails in the same way.